# Selecting similarly named elements within different divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, naming-conventions

Say I have the following divs in my page:

```
<div id="person_1">
  Name: <span>Bob</span> <br>
  Gender: <span>Male</span>
</div>

<div id="person_2">
  Name: <span>Sally</span> <br>
  Gender: <span>Female</span>
</div>
```

If I wanted to update the name or gender of person 1, I can't think of any way to select that span, except if I changed the spans to:

```
<span id="person_1_name">Bob</span>
<span id="person_1_gender">Male</span>
```

And:

```
<span id="person_2_name">Sally</span>
<span id="person_2_gender">Female</span>
```

And then I could do: `$("#person_1_name").html(bob.newName);`. However, that's very ugly and not my preference.

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
$("#person_1 name").html(bob.newName);
$("#person_1 age").html(bob.newAge);

$("#person_2 name").html(sally.newName);
$("#person_2 age").html(sally.newAge);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use:

```
<div id="person_1">
  Name: <span class="name">Bob</span> <br>
  Gender: <span class="gender">Male</span>
</div>
```

Then the jquery for selecting the name for person 1 would be

```
$('#person_1 .name').text();
```

**Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/zSqjV/1/**

Otherwise, if you don't want to change the HTML and you know that name will always be the first span in the div and gender will always be the last span in the div, you can use this:

```
var person1_name = $('#person_1 span:first').text();
var person1_gender = $('#person_1 span:last').text();
```

Comment: I was just going to say that. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the following instead of using classes

```
$("#person_1 > span:first").text(newname);
$("#person_1 > span:last").text(newage);
```

Comment: Nice one :) I was just adding that to mine but you beat me ;)

Comment: This is really not recommended :P

Comment: Please tell us why if not so :) if there is something wrong maybe I can also learn

Answer (score 1):

You can use classes to identify your span elements, like this:

```
<div id="person_1">
  Name: <span class="name">Bob</span> <br>
  Gender: <span class="gender">Male</span>
  Age: <span class="age">25</span>
</div>

<div id="person_2">
  Name: <span class="name">Sally</span> <br>
  Gender: <span class="gender">Female</span>
  Age: <span class="age">21</span>
</div>
```

And then you code like this:

```
$("#person_1 .name").html(bob.newName);
$("#person_1 .age").html(bob.newAge);

$("#person_2 .name").html(sally.newName);
$("#person_2 .age").html(sally.newAge);
```

Alternatively, you could change your `<span>` tags to `<name>` or `<age>` tags, but this isn't HTML compliant, and you could run into all kinds of cross browser issues now or in the future, so I wouldn't recommend it.